# Authorization in php, without further saving the password and login, which is a connection to the Oracle database

Tags: php, oci8

Modeling the situation:
The user enters his login and password in the form on the `auth.php` page, the data is sent,

```php
new ConnectToDB($user,$password)
```

happens, he is authorized and redirected to the `example.php` page On which the select request to the database occurs through the

```php
new ExampleModel($dbConnect)
```

instance, `$dbConnect` must have a connection to the database obtained from the `auth.php` page similarly on other pages

I experienced: storage of connections in sessions; connection storage in pseudo-globally install; storing them in a separate facility; create SessionManager; and other options Caused connection = null on new pages, or oci8 resource could not be passed

Comment: You have stated what you have done and what you have experienced but you do not appear to have asked a question so it is unclear what problem you want to solve.

Comment: Web applications are generally stateless - meaning that you can't have user-specific connections to the back-end database like a desktop application would because there's no secure way (as you've seen) to pass that information from one page to the next. Most web applications use a single set of common credentials to open a pool of generic sessions, then grab an existing connection from the pool just long enough to execute an individual SQL command. Generic application database credentials are stored in a secure wallet or keystore of some kind for security.

Comment: ... Detailed user session data is then tracked in the database or some key-value store, with minimal data like a session id persisted for the user in the application URL or in a browser cookie. This is a general, over-simplified explanation: there are a variety of ways this could happen behind the scenes depending on your specific infrastructure and application architecture.

Comment: @pmdba Will the following solutions work? 1) Creating your own application state controller and storing $user, $password there, to access them from any page, like Redux does, but only without the ability to access / view states from the client side. 2) Try to make a SPA, and after authorization create a connection to the database, save it to the $dbConnect variable, and $login and remove $password. Will I be able to access $dbConnect using SPA logic? 3) Storing data in a file on the server, but honestly I think this is a so-so idea.

Comment: My technology stack: php8/php8.2.3; oci8; oracle11g; linux; apache; php-fpm; javascript without the use of third-party libraries, the closer to vanilla the better.

Comment: i would not re-invent the wheel with anything security-related. i would go with an industry standard method of database access and session control. Separate application authentication from database authentication. Store generic application db credentials in a secure (encrypted) wallet on the app server. User application credentials map to data in a table, not to actual database accounts.

Comment: This very old article might still have some useful tips:  [PHP Web Auditing, Authorization and Monitoring with Oracle Database](https://developer.oracle.com/learn/technical-articles/php-web-auditing).  I agree with other comments that you should use something industry standard but the article will give some background.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass resources between http requests in PHP - each HTTP request starts PHP with a blank canvas. You need to persist the username and password in the session and reconnect in each script.